# wso2 axis2 OutOfMemory few times a day

Tags: java, wso2, apache-axis, wso2-esb

What is the possible reason of constant OOM errors?

On our developement environment we have 3 nodes, VM on master node is initialized with: Xms=3GB, Xmx=3GB. Also there are about 30 proxies and 30 endpoints defined. Developers loading their changes (car files) constantly during the day without restarting carbon. Few times a day it freezes. Maybe constant configartion changes kill carbon? On preproduction environment carbon works flawlessly :/

I did heap dump and the 'leak suspect report' result is:

> One instance of "org.apache.axis2.context.ConfigurationContext" loaded
> by     "axis2" occupies 661 590 744 (79,50%) bytes. The memory is
> accumulated in one instance of
> "java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap$Segment[]" loaded by "".

Report result:
[image: Report]

Histogram:
[image: Histogram]

Comment: what is the ESB version you are using?

Comment: We are using 4.9.0 version.

Comment: For a typical deployment wso2 suggest to have below GC configuration. -Xms512m -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m Since you are using 3gb of RAM you have to adjust that based on your scenario. You can refer to https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Production+Deployment+Guidelines for more information regarding the deployments

Comment: Freezing happens mostly due to full gc cycles happening in the system, You can change your gc settings in order to do a proper gc configuration

Comment: Check this blog [Axis2 ConfigurationContext usage and possible memory leak](http://sudheerjava6.blogspot.com/2015/07/axis2-configurationcontext-usage-and.html) It has some recommendation to avoid memory leak issue with Axis2 client.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the Heap Dump most of the retained heap is occupied by the ConfigurationContext instances. So this OOM issue seems to occur due to the heavy configuration load in your development system. May be due to large capps deployed frequently by lot of developers. Since that incident does not happen in your production, that ESB never goes OOM.

Thanks & Regards,
Ravindra.

Answer (score 0):

Freezing happens mostly due to full gc cycles happening in the system, You can change your gc settings in order to do a proper gc configuration

For a typical deployment wso2 suggest to have below GC configuration. -**Xms512m -Xmx2048m -XX:MaxPermSize=1024m** Since you are using 3gb of RAM you have to adjust that based on your scenario. You can refer to https://docs.wso2.com/display/CLUSTER44x/Production+Deployment+Guidelines for more information regarding the deployments

Since you are using Xms=3GB, Xmx=3GB there is a possibility it will wait until the whole 3gb get filled and then do full gc cycles. Therefore better to adjust the Xms value to about 1gb so it motivate to have minor gc cycles and cleanup the unnecessary stuffs rather than waiting for full gc